# When Click on embed youtube video - redirect

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, youtube

Hello I have embed video on my site and I want to redirect on new site when user click play button it is possible?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well if you redirect the user as soon as he wants to watch the video, whats the point of embedding it in the first place?

You could just put the thumbnail on your page and make it link to whatever site you want.
Or just any element and use Javascript to redirect as soon as you click on it.

Also this doesnt really have anything to do with php since you want to do that clientside.